# Filling information via Backend (?) - How to

Tags: javascript, vue.js, content-management-system, backend

Community,

we are developing a WebApp in Vue.js which is working pretty steady right now.

However, even after searching a lot on google, I cannot find a starting point for a specific topic.

As our pretty tough timeframe may lead to coding one or two components, we would like to simulate responsiveness via fast uploading of these components. Right now we are only uploading via FTP and always updating the whole file. Is there, even with vue, a more easier way to upload only one component?

Second: We are integrating a block. One option is using a CMS ofc. However, we would like to do it via code but no code team members need to write and publish articles via the platform. How is this possible? I am thinking of a input mask directly pushing in our data structure coded dynamically via HTML/ CSS / JS.

Looking forward to answers or links. Just a starting point is very much appreciated!

Best,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say good start to begin with:

- an RESTful `API` via back-end for CRUD for your database : can be simple codeigniter into good practice of Laravel, or Firebase for quick prototyping
- your vue webApp as front-end/client-side: using `Axios` (kinda like AJAX but no need JQuery anymore for applications) for handling GET/POST/PUT requests thru the API. And ofc, along with good authentication approach according project's needs. If you have major/tremendous updates, at least the content can be dynamically fetched despite of version update in your production build of vueApp.

Hope this give some insights. :)